# R: Checking if values in columns match, no matter the order

Tags: r

I have two columns and I would like to check if the values match in these columns, the order of the values in the columns doesn't matter.

For example

```
a  b
1  2
2  3
3  1
```

This would be a match in my example while:

```
a  b
1  4
2  3
3  1
```

Wouldn't be a match.

I thought about using sum and diff but there would be too many other constellations without a real match, that would indicate a match with this method.

Comment: try `all(df$a %in% df$b)`; see `all(1:3 %in% 3:1)`

Comment: Do you care about duplicates? If not, `setequal(df$a, df$b)` will check if the values overlap totally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
identical(sort(df$a), sort(df$b))
```

This will be true if the two have the same numbers. Here I assume they're columns in a data frame:

```
df <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "a  b
1  2
2  3
3  1")
```